# Data exists and not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

Table 1

```
Claim_id
Claim_Status -- Includes values of "PAID" and "DENIED"
```

Table 2 - This table contains same claims from Table 1 but with line item details.

```
Claim_id 
Line_number 
Status -- Includes values of "PAID" and "DENIED"
```

A PAID status `claim_id` from table 1 could have some lines with `Status` = "DENIED" from table 2

A particular paid claim could have few lines denied in it.

I need to pull number of claims where all lines are in "PAID" status, 
and number of claims where some lines are "PAID" and some lines are "DENIED" for a given `claim_id`.

```
SELECT x.claim_id, x.claim_status, x.payer_id1
FROM HEADER_CLAIM_TABLE x
WHERE x.payer_id1 = 'company_Z' 
      AND x.claim_id in (SELECT a.CLAIM_ID,
                                a.LINE_NUMBER,
                                a.STATUS,
                                a.payer_id
                         FROM LINE_DETAIL_CLAIM_TABLE a
                         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.*
                                       FROM LINE_DETAIL_CLAIM_TABLE B
                                       WHERE b.status = 'DENIED')
                               AND a.claim_id = b.claim_id
                               AND a.line_number = b.line_number
                               AND a.payer_id = b.payer_id)
      AND x.claim_status = 'PAID'
```

I am new to this so please excuse if the above query is totally off course. Please help in getting this data pulled.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Its Oracle.

Comment: why you sould do this for a given claim_id ? Maybe for a given claim id you  can get the num of lines paid or denied...

Comment: i want to find # of claims which are partially paid (e.g some lines paid and some lines denied) and # of claims fully paid (all lines in "PAID" status)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some old style sql..try this

```
select claim_with_no_deny.cnt PAID_COUNT,  claim_with_deny.cnt    WITH_DENY_COUNT
from
(select count(*) cnt from HEADER_CLAIM_TABLE h where 
  exists (select 1 from LINE_DETAIL_CLAIM_TABLE D where h.claim_id=d.claim_id and d.status = 'DENIED') claim_with_deny,
(select count(*) cnt from HEADER_CLAIM_TABLE h where 
 not exists (select 1 from LINE_DETAIL_CLAIM_TABLE D where h.claim_id=d.claim_id and d.status = 'DENIED') claim_with_no_deny
```